# Error in writing custom module in ejabbers XMPP server

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I run a small private group of users on an `XMPP server` and recently I needed to write a custom module. To start write a custom module, I followed this [tutorial][1].

As I have not written a custom module before and being at an low intermediate level with Erlang I decided to go for the basics - following Jack Moffits mod_sunshine.erl example as well as Anders Conbere's examples.

I am running ejabberd-13.12 community edition on Ubuntu LTS 12.04. For the life of me I can not get mod_sunshine to work or even just a basic skeletal module to work (see below mod_test.erl).

I compile to a beam file, I edit the ejabberd.cfg file (in ejabberd-13.12 it is ejabberd.yml). I restart and get the following error:

```
gen_mod:start_module:78 Problem starting the module mod_sunshine for
host <<"xmpp1.xxxxx.com">>
options: []
error: undef
```

I have found very little on the internet resolving this problem. Maybe there are about a half dozen posts out there with the `gen_mod:start_module:78 error` but no real solutions.

I have wasted 2 days trying to figure this out. Even trying on another server using `ejabberd-2.1.10` but no dice.

Below is the barest custom module I've tested but still get the same error.

```
-module(mod_test).

-behaviour(gen_mod).

-export([start/2, stop/1]).

start(_Host, _Opt) -> ok.

stop(_Host) -> ok.
```

Can anyone help me please?. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Attach an Erlang shell to the ejabberd node by running `ejabberdctl debug` from the command line.  In the shell, type `l(mod_test).` (the final dot is important).  Does that return `{module, mod_test}` or an error?

Comment: Do you have the same module name in configuration and in the ejabberd paths? The log messages shows `mod_sunshine` and source code has `mod_test`. If you have the same names, the problem is probably you have put your module in a wrong place and ejabberd can't find it.